# What two laws of harmonics are demonstrated here?

Tags: fft, harmonics, spectrum

I clipped the top and bottom of a sine wave at exact reciprocal angles (73.73159173° to 106.2684083° and 253.73159173° to 286.2684083°) to prevent the creation of even (red) harmonics (by being perfectly symmetrical).[image: Bullard Plot of 2% symmetrical clipping] Then I performed an FFT, then multiplied ALL the harmonics by various multipliers (2, 4, 8, 16, -2, -4, -8 and -16) (6 dB in each case). Notice that the negative values don't appear in this MAGNITUDE plot which only shows positive values. Since I multiplied the harmonics in complex form, only the phases of the harmonics is affected by the sign of the multiplier. [image: Spectrum of modified FFT] I got this really cool looking wave after doing the inverse FFT.[image: Composite wave] Here is a closeup of the positive peak.[image: Composite wave positive peak closeup] Notice that I never touched the fundamental, the 1st harmonic. What two laws of physics does this experiments prove?

Comment: Question might be a better for https://physics.stackexchange.com/ or even https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What two laws do you think it proves?

Answer (score 3):

It's not physics but pretty straightforward maths:

The harmonics represent the fourier expansion of the bit of the fundamental you chopped off:

[image]

and, by scaling all the harmonics by the same factor,  you are adding varying amounts of it - hence you are seeing a fourier approximation to this added to your waveform with varying scale factors, hence the picture.